# How to know the progressive state of mind in insight meditation

Tags: enlightenment

While  doing  meditation thoughts  developing on cittarupa and the what is appearing  on the field too disappears together feel like anattma(non self).At that moment citta goes out into the field and light appears from  the point it has gone.no attachment it is freed and moved towards. No sensations of body has appeared. (Eg sound ....,...,)what is this experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the speed of letting go of things is one of the indicators from [Indriya-bhavana Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.152.than.html)

> There is the case where, when seeing a form with the eye, there arises
>   in a monk what is agreeable, what is disagreeable, what is agreeable &
>   disagreeable. He discerns that 'This agreeable thing has arisen in me,
>   this disagreeable thing... this agreeable & disagreeable thing has
>   arisen in me. And that is compounded, gross, dependently co-arisen.
>   But this is peaceful, this is exquisite, i.e., equanimity.' With that,
>   the arisen agreeable thing... disagreeable thing... agreeable &
>   disagreeable thing ceases, and equanimity takes its stance. Just as a
>   man with good eyes, having closed them, might open them; or having
>   opened them, might close them, **that is how quickly, how rapidly, how
>   easily,** no matter what it refers to, the arisen agreeable thing...
>   disagreeable thing... agreeable & disagreeable thing ceases, and
>   equanimity takes its stance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the fourth one, the udayabbaya nana. Seeing light is very common at that stage. There are other phenomena that can occur. It differs with each person. Just keep noting, it will go away sooner or later.

You could check the list on the
[website of Vipassana Dhura](http://www.vipassanadhura.com/sixteen.html#foura).